# Astar error commpiling Swanky

Tags: astar

Trying to compile smart contract and it gives me this error, in charge .toml I put the direct routes and nothing. Other smart contracts compile with ink! properly.

Command I use: `cargo +nightly contract build --release` and error I got:

```
ERROR: Loading Cargo.toml

Caused by:
     No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

Comment: Can you please write down [specific instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to duplicate your error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @polkadot/util has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
 cjs 10.2.1  node_modules/@astar-network/swanky-cli/node_modules/@polkadot/util-crypto/node_modules/@polkadot/util/cjs
 cjs 10.1.13 node_modules/@astar-network/swanky-cli/node_modules/@polkadot/util/cjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you add more details to your question, for now is not specified enough to give some valuable input. I can share my experience with `swanky-node` (maybe is related). When you will try to build firstly the node like below:

> tomek@rhei-box:~/workspaces/swanky-node$ cargo build
> [2022-12-20T22:49:25Z INFO  cargo_release::release] Publishing
> pallet-chain-extension-rmrk
> Updating crates.io index error: all dependencies must have a version specified when publishing. dependency `frame-support` does not
> specify a version Note: The published dependency will use the version
> from crates.io, the `git` specification will be removed from the
> dependency declaration.

You can get errors, but when you execute `cargo build --release` immediately after cloning repository, everything should compile successfully.